# adding new column to pandas dataframe with values for particular items?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
d=pandas.DataFrame([{"a": 1}, {"a": 3, "b": 2}])
```

and I'm trying to add a new column to it with non-null values only for certain rows, based on their numeric indices in the array. for example, adding a new column "c" only to the first row in `d`:

```
# array of row indices
indx = np.array([0])
d.ix[indx]["c"] = "foo"
```

which should add "foo" as the column "c" value for the first row, and NaN for all other rows. but this doesn't seem to change the array:

```
d.ix[np.array([0])]["c"] = "foo"
In [18]: d
Out[18]: 
   a   b
0  1 NaN
1  3   2
```

what am I doing wrong here? how can it be done? thanks.

Comment: If this is anything like a numpy array , shouldn't this be homogeneous ?

Comment: It's very possible to have a pandas df with a mixture of string values and NaN values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([{"a": 1}, {"a": 3, "b": 2}])

In [12]: df['c'] = np.array(['foo',np.nan])

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
   a   b    c
0  1 NaN  foo
1  3   2  nan
```

If you were assigning a numeric value, the following would work

```
In [16]: df['c'] = np.nan

In [17]: df.ix[0,'c'] = 1

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
   a   b   c
0  1 NaN   1
1  3   2 NaN
```

Comment: I knew it would work if I assigned an entire array to `df['c']` but is there no way to assign just particular elements and have it infer the rest are `NaN`? It looks like I have to explicitly construct an array of size `len(df)` with nans and non-values...

Comment: ``df['c'].update(pd.Series(['foo'],index=[0]))`` should work, but this is a bug right now, if your assignments are numeric then you can just use my second example

Comment: thanks. they are not numeric, so I'll just stick to manually constructing the whole array

Comment: ok...I fixed this bug in 0.11-dev in any event, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3219 thanks!